# Two Shopify Discount Apps In Conflict

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

I'm working on a Shopify site for the first time, and the client has very specific discount rules, which I'm using two apps to fulfill. The two discount types are wholesale discounts, and volume discounts. The apps, however, overlap in certain instances. If a wholesale vendor buys items that already have a volume discount, the discount is applied to the lower price, and they get a double discount.

This is expected, but not desired.

I'm hoping to change the code to be something like:

`IF (logged in user is a vendor)
   regular item price
ELSE 
   shappify-price`

The two apps I'm using are wholesale hero, and BOLD's tiered price breaks. BOLD has refused to help me, saying they don't support the other app. BOLD's app also uses variants to define the different tiers.

My real question is, if I find a way to modify the liquid and snippets, will that have any effect on what goes into checkout? or are the liquid files only for what is displayed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is a totally impossible problem without coding my own apps, please let me know.

Comment: How do you plan to identify a vendor?